# unit testing & constructor dependency injection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an issue regarding how one would go about designing an application suited for unit-testing.

I am trying to implement the SRP (Single-Responsibility Principle), and from what I understood this involves splitting out most functionality in seperate, dedicated classes to keep code more organised.  For example, I have this specific scenario.

A class `RecurringProfile`, which has a method `.ActivateProfile()`.  What this method does is mark the status as activated, and create the next (first) recurring payment for the next due date.  I was going to split out the functionality to create the next recurring payment in a seperate class, for example `RecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator`.    My instant idea is to have this class take the `'RecurringProfile'` as a parameter in it's constructor:

```
RecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator(IRecurringProfile profile)
```

However, I think this would be problematic for unit-testing.   I would like to create a unit-test which tests out the `ActivateProfile` functionality.  This method would get an instance of an `IRecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator` via dependency injection (Ninject), and call the method `.CreateNextPayment`.

My idea to create a unit-test was to create a mock of an `IRecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator`, and substitue that so that I can verify that the `.ActivateProfile()` actually called the method.  However, due to the constructor parameter, this would not fit as a default constructor for NInject.  Having to create a custom NInject provider just for such a case (where I can have many such classes all over the solution) would be a bit overkill.

Any ideas / best practices how one would go about this?

--
Below is a sample code regarding the above example: (Please note that the code is hand-written, and is not syntactically 100% correct)

```
public class RecurringProfile
{
    public void ActivateProfile()
    {
        this.Status = Enums.ProfileStatus.Activated;
        //now it should create the first recurring payment
        IRecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator creator = NInject.Get<IRecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator>();
        creator.CreateNextPayment(this); //this is what I'm having an issue about 
    }
}
```

And a sample unit-test:

```
public void TestActivateProfile()
{   
    var mockPaymentCreator = new Mock<IRecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator>();
    NInject.Bind<IRecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator>(mockPaymentCreator.Object);

    RecurringProfile profile = new RecurringProfile();
    profile.ActivateProfile();
    Assert.That(profile.Status == Enums.ProfileStatus.Activated);
    mockPayment.Verify(x => x.CreateNextPayment(), Times.Once());

}
```

Going up to the sample code, my issue is whether it is a good practice to pass over the RecurringProfile as a parameter to the `creator.CreateNextPayment()` method, or whether it makes more sense to somehow pass the `RecurringProfile` to the DI-framework, when getting an instance of an `IRecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator`, considering that the `IRecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator` will always act on an `IRecurringProfile` to create the next payment. Hope this makes the question a bit more clear.

Comment: @KellyEthridge make this an answer not a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you did not show any code I'm guessing that you want to do something like this

```cs
public class RecurringProfile
{
  private readonly DateTime _dueDate;
  private readonly TimeSpan _interval;
  public RecurringProfile(DateTime dueDate, TimeSpan interval)
  {
    _dueDate = dueDate;
    _interval = interval;
  }
  public bool IsActive { get; private set; }
  public DateTime DueDate
  {
    get { return _dueDate; }
  }
  public TimeSpan Interval
  {
    get { return _interval; }
  }
  public RecurringProfile ActivateProfile()
  {
    this.IsActive = true;
    return new RecurringProfile(this.DueDate + this.Interval, this.Interval);
  }
}
```

Isn't that simple enough?

---

**Update**

Don't abuse a DI container as a ServiceLocator. Your idea to inject the payment creator as ctor parameter is the right way to go. [ServiceLocator is considered an anti-pattern in modern application architecture](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). Something like the code below should work fine.

```cs
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void TestMethod1()
  {
    var mock = new Mock<INextPaymentCreator>();
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    var current = new RecurringProfile(mock.Object, dt, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
    current.ActivateProfile();
    mock.Verify(c => c.CreateNextPayment(current), Times.Once());
  }
}
public class RecurringProfile
{
  private readonly INextPaymentCreator _creator;
  private readonly DateTime _dueDate;
  private readonly TimeSpan _interval;
  public RecurringProfile(INextPaymentCreator creator, DateTime dueDate, TimeSpan interval)
  {
    _creator = creator;
    _dueDate = dueDate;
    _interval = interval;
  }
  public bool IsActive { get; private set; }
  public DateTime DueDate
  {
    get { return _dueDate; }
  }
  public TimeSpan Interval
  {
    get { return _interval; }
  }
  public RecurringProfile ActivateProfile()
  {
    this.IsActive = true;
    var next = this._creator.CreateNextPayment(this);
    return next;
  }
}

public interface INextPaymentCreator
{
  RecurringProfile CreateNextPayment(RecurringProfile current);
}
```

Comment: I didn't post any code because the code is not yet developed, and this is more of a design/best-practice issue.  I'm still getting up to grasps with the IoC/DI principles - I'll re-edit the original post with some sample code to get a better idea what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I was reading in more detail on the Service Locator anti-pattern, and other DI anti-patterns and it seems I was on the wrong track and this looks much neater and makes more sense now.  To be honest, I was already finding the 'automatic' resolving of dependencies via the Service-Locator pattern which I was using confusing as it totally hides the dependencies, and this has now cleared it up :)

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be using your DI container(Ninject) during such unit-tests. You would manually inject the mock object when newing up the class under test. Then verify the call was made on the mock.

Comment: @KellyEhtridge What exactly do you mean by 'manually inject'?  Maybe you could provide a code-snippet / sample just to give an idea?  As far as I know, one of the main roles of DI is to be able to substitute objects with mock objects for unit-testing.

Comment: @SebastianWeber That's an interesting read - However, my main issue isn't exactly that.  The Poor man's DI explains about having concrete implementations in the constructor.  In my case, my issue is whether one should create the class implementing `IRecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator' with a constructor taking the `IRecurringProfile` and somehow passing it, or whether the method `IRecurringProfileNextPaymentCreator.CreateNextPayment()` should take the `IRecurringProfile` as a parameter to the method.

Comment: @KarlCassar I was just answering your question "What exactly do you mean by 'manually inject'?"